# Buying New Electronics During the 9 Days

Tags: technology, nine-days, transactions

Is one allowed to buy new electronic devices during the nine days (e.g. cellphone, laptop)?

Comment: As always, for practical guidance, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ohr.edu/1097

> One should not purchase an object of joy that will be available after
>   Tisha B’Av for the same price.

Comment: But what is their source for such a prohibition? And even if there are grounds to include all "objects of joy", who said the electronics are objects of joy? Electronics nowadays might be reasonably considered common appliances.